# How to dynamically change text of checkable icon?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt

In my QGIS plugin, I have a checkable [QIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qicon.html) which changes image depending on its state.

Is it also possible to change its tooltip text (i.e. if icon is checked, the text would read "*myPlugin ON*"; unchecked would read "*myPlugin OFF*")?

At the moment, it only reads "*myPlugin*". This is the code I use:

```
def add_action(
    self,
    toolbar,
    icon_path,
    text,
    callback,
    checkable=False,
    enabled_flag=True,
    add_to_menu=True,
    add_to_toolbar=True,
    status_tip=None,
    whats_this=None,
    parent=None):

    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)
    action.setCheckable(checkable)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

    if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)

    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)
    return action

def initGui(self):
    icon = QIcon()
    icon.addFile( ':/plugins/myPlugin/icons/Off.png', state=QIcon.Off )
    icon.addFile( ':/plugins/myPlugin/icons/On.png', state=QIcon.On )
    self.pluginButton = self.add_action(
        self.toolbar,
        icon,
        text=self.tr(u'myPlugin'),
        callback=self.myFunc,
        checkable=True,
        enabled_flag=False,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
```

---

*I am using QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit.*

Comment: this is a theoretical thought: currently, you call the "tr" function. what if you call a custom function which checks which state the checkbox has, and then call "tr" function with the string "plugin on/off" respectively

Comment: a more detailed idea: in the function, you could try with `icon.state()´ or `icon.Mode()` and see if something changes to get the state of the icon and thus change the text. sorry for not writting a more detailed idear but i currently cant test it :(

Comment: Your last idea led me to a solution. I have a `self.myFunc` callback function which checks the state already. I simply had to add `self.pluginButton.setText('myPlugin ON')` when state is true and the opposite when state is false. Can you post it as an answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the results from the comments:

Create a callback function which catches the `icon.State()` and check its value:

The function could look like this:

```
myFunc(self):
   if icon.State() == 1: # disabled
      self.pluginButton.setText('myPlugin OFF')
   elif icon.State() == 0: # enabeld
      self.pluginButton.setText('myPlugin On')
```

---

Or alternatively:

```
myFunc(self, checked):
   if checked:
      self.pluginButton.setText('myPlugin ON')
   else:
      self.pluginButton.setText('myPlugin OFF')
```

Comment: @Joseph most welcome!